# Media player audio,in countdown timer on Tick method,gets mute after 10 second

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set a Tick sound/audio in one of my app in the countdown timer on tick method,but after a 10 seconds this mediaplayer audio becomes mute,can anyone check this..

[the audio is available here](http://soundbible.com/2044-Tick.html)

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(seekBar.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000) { 

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.i("started", "that");
            Log.i("seconds left", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
            taskupdate((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tick);
            mediaPlayer2.start();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.airhorn);
            mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Oh, you create MediaPlayer on every tick.....

Comment: Yes,Mediaplayer is started on every tick(so as to get the feeling of clock tick),can you please help me get a solution

Comment: You should not create it every time. Create it once and then start every tick

Comment: @AntonA.,Thank You Very Much,I got it.How can I put green tick against your answer.